# How can I used Fairseq model in inference mode?

Tags: python, pytorch, type-inference, speech-to-text, fairseq

I've build a speech to text translation model using Fairseq library. Now I want to use it in inference mode without using fairseq-generate commandline. How can I process ?

thanks in advance